# Are almost positive functionals close to positive functionals?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras

This is a bit of an open-ended question... Let $S$ be an operator algebra (or an operator system) and consider a functional $\nu:M\to \mathbb{C}$ 
that satisfies 
$$\vert \nu(a)\vert \ge -\varepsilon \Vert a\Vert$$
for every $a\ge A$?
My question is:

> Is there a positive functional near $f$? By this I mean is there $\delta>0$ the relies on $\varepsilon$ and a positive functional $\mu:M\to \mathbb{C}$ such that $\Vert \mu-\nu\Vert\le \delta$?

If the answer is no in general, are there any conditions that would imply a positive answer? Or would it work for some examples maybe?

Comment: Could you clarify the meanings of $S$, $A$ and $M$  in your statement?